# What specific backend framework or language should I use?

Tags: backend

I'm a graduating student from UST,Philippines and one requirement for us before we graduate is to take up software engineering and our professor told us to make a user management system with these specifications:
1. CRUD of user management
- add & login users
-forget pass (intranet)
-3 wrong attempt login - locked account (the admin is the one to unlock)
-user - can view accounts only
-admin- edit accounts
-ID is system generated
-have high security
-XML Database (once opened, show data)

He said that we should integrate MVP model. I am not familiar with backend programming. Hoping you can help me. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, PHP is the language more easily to learn.
With it you can use many good frameworks and well documented: Zend Framework, Symphony, CodeIgniter, WordPress (have much ready thing in WordPress, mainly relationship of users, login, users list, user management) ...

Comment: Rather than complain about my answer, help him.  This question cannot be answered subjectively.

Comment: Most questions that cannot be answered subjectively should not be asked on Stack Overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask